# Popup Menu text translation of "What's This"

Tags: c++, qt

Where and how can I override the "What's This" text of the popup menu, which shows up, when pressing the RMB on a QT dialog control?

Comment: Either load the correct Qt translations for your selected language or create a custom popup menu by yourself.

Comment: Thx, but they seem to be loaded already, as all other texts in the dialog get translated properly.
Custom Popup - ok - but how? An RMB popup I already have - is there a way to globally override the "What's This" Balloon-Tip with proper translation texts?

Comment: I said you should load the Qt translation, additionally to your own to translate texts defined inside the Qt source code.

Comment: Ok. Fully understood - thank you.
But what if I want to add just the single "What's This" text translation to my own .qm file, without using the general QT translation? As which entry shall I add it?

Comment: Then you have to look into the Qt sources to find out the correct context for the translation and use e.g. [QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/i18n-source-translation.html#using-qt-tr-noop-and-qt-translate-noop-in-c) with the correct namespace and add the string to your code so it gets picked up by lupdate